# Swift: UIView not resizing to fit content

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, uistackview

I am building an app in which I have a list of Reviews. They look like the following screenshot
[image: Review]
For some reason, I am failing to make the UIView (Gray box from the top light gray line to the bottom one) resize correctly. The white text inside it (Actual review) is longer than 1 line and should not get cut off, only when reaching a maximum of say 5 lines. The thing is, it works when I don't set width and height constraints for the user image you see on the left side. Removing those will make the view resize correctly, but it will completely distort the image. The image top and botton anchors seem to be glued to the anchors in its horizontal stackview, which again are stuck to the UIView's top and botton anchors with constants, as it should. But nowhere do I say that the UIView should always have the size of the image. I don't get why it wont go bigger than the image.

Here is a screenshot of my structure with the constraints, hope it is clear enough:
[image: Structure]

```
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                //Main horizontal stackview (one Rating is the name of the UIView)
                hStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oneRating.leadingAnchor, constant: 23),
                hStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oneRating.trailingAnchor, constant: -18),
                hStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oneRating.topAnchor, constant: 15),
                hStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oneRating.bottomAnchor, constant: -13),
                
                reviewerImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
                reviewerImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
                                    
                //Limit the size of the Review Text to make sure its always at the same spot
                v2Stack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 220.0),
            ])
            
            //Verified checkmark constraints
            if isUserVerified == true {
                reviewerVerified.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: reviewerImage.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
                reviewerVerified.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: reviewerImage.trailingAnchor, constant: -2).isActive = true
            }
```

I know it is hard to help like this but I have tried to fix this for a few days and no matter what I do, I can't get it to work.

EDIT:
As per request, here is the code I have to add the ImageView to my UIView().

```
                //Add Image
            let reviewerImage = UIImageView()
            reviewerImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            reviewerImage.layer.cornerRadius = 40 //= 1/2 of width, because we hard coded the size
            reviewerImage.image = UIImage(named: "person-icon") //Placeholder. Download image here
```

reviewerImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
VStack1.addArrangedSubview(reviewerImage)

Comment: Is this inside a UITableView ?

Comment: @PtitXav No, it's part of a scroll view but it should not make a difference, right?

Comment: Could you list all the constraints you have defined for the image ? It could that a constraint on image is is in fact constraining its superview.

Comment: @claude31 they're all there! It's literally just the width and the height. That's why I am not understanding it. I will add the code I use to add the ImageView to my UIView, maybe that helps.

Comment: How did you define "The white text inside it (Actual review) is longer than 1 line". Is it a label ? Have set the number of lines to 0 in IB ? Or to another value ?

Comment: @claude31 I have set
 reviewText.numberOfLines = 5 //Max 5 lines, else break it with ...

Comment: @JanL : i asked you because default size  of cells is define by tableView not cell. But it has nothing to be with your case. How do you compute scroll view contents size ?

Comment: @PtitXav The scrollview fills the whole view, inside of there lays a stackview which again is filled by uiviews, each of them having dynamic content of their own. Each view needs a certain height, which fills the stackviews, which sets the overall height for each view including the scrollview. I do not set any sizes directly, exept for the image size for example and some other parts of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You *will* need to add a few more sizing constraints, but...

The "trick" is to embed your "reviewer image view" in a clear "container" view. Then constrain the image view to the Top of that container.

Here is some sample code that gets close to your layout:

```
class JanView: UIView {
    
    let reviewerImageView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        return v
    }()
    let starImageView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        return v
    }()
    let chevronImageView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        return v
    }()
    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        return v
    }()
    let locLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        return v
    }()
    let reviewTextLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.numberOfLines = 5
        return v
    }()
    let publishedLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        return v
    }()
    let starValueLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        backgroundColor = .darkGray
        
        let outerHStack: UIStackView = {
            let v = UIStackView()
            v.spacing = 10
            return v
        }()
        let labelsVStack: UIStackView = {
            let v = UIStackView()
            v.axis = .vertical
            v.spacing = 0
            return v
        }()
        let starsAndChevronVStack: UIStackView = {
            let v = UIStackView()
            v.axis = .vertical
            v.spacing = 0
            return v
        }()
        let starsHStack: UIStackView = {
            let v = UIStackView()
            v.spacing = 0
            v.alignment = .center
            return v
        }()
        
        // review image container
        let reviewerImageContainer: UIView = {
            let v = UIView()
            return v
        }()
        
        [nameLabel, reviewTextLabel].forEach { v in
            v.textColor = .white
        }
        [locLabel, publishedLabel].forEach { v in
            v.textColor = .lightGray
        }
        starValueLabel.textColor = .systemYellow
        
        outerHStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        addSubview(outerHStack)
        
        [nameLabel, locLabel, reviewTextLabel, publishedLabel].forEach { v in
            labelsVStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        [starValueLabel, starImageView].forEach { v in
            starsHStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        [starsHStack, chevronImageView].forEach { v in
            starsAndChevronVStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        [reviewerImageContainer, labelsVStack, starsAndChevronVStack].forEach { v in
            outerHStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        
        // add reviewer image view to container
        reviewerImageContainer.addSubview(reviewerImageView)
        reviewerImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // specific properties
        reviewerImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        reviewerImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 40
        reviewerImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        let cfg = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 12.0, weight: .bold)
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: "star.fill", withConfiguration: cfg) {
            starImageView.image = img
        }
        starImageView.tintColor = .systemYellow
        starImageView.contentMode = .center
        starValueLabel.text = "4"
        
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.right", withConfiguration: cfg) {
            chevronImageView.image = img
        }
        chevronImageView.tintColor = .lightGray
        chevronImageView.contentMode = .center
        
        nameLabel.text = "Name Here"
        locLabel.text = "Location Here"
        reviewTextLabel.text = "Review Text Here"
        publishedLabel.text = "Published Info Here"
        
        let g = self
        
        // to get the 2nd vertical stack view to fit (horizontally) to its content
        let sacWidth = starsAndChevronVStack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10.0)
        sacWidth.priority = .defaultHigh
        
        let vPadding: CGFloat = 12
        let hPadding: CGFloat = 10
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            outerHStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: vPadding),
            outerHStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: hPadding),
            outerHStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -hPadding),
            outerHStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -vPadding),
            
            reviewerImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0),
            reviewerImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: reviewerImageView.widthAnchor),
            
            // align the reviewer image view with the top of the container view
            reviewerImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: reviewerImageContainer.topAnchor),
            reviewerImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: reviewerImageContainer.leadingAnchor),
            reviewerImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: reviewerImageContainer.trailingAnchor),

            // give the stars value label a width, so it doesn't vary by text
            //  "5" is wider than "1" (or it may be "" ?)
            starValueLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 16.0),
            
            // make the star image view square
            starImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: starImageView.heightAnchor),
            
            // make the stars HStack height equal to the stars label height
            starsHStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: starValueLabel.heightAnchor),
            
            sacWidth,
            
        ])
        
    }
    
}
```

and an example controller:

```
class ReviewVC: UIViewController {
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        return v
    }()
    let reviewsStack: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.spacing = 0
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [reviewsStack, scrollView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        scrollView.addSubview(reviewsStack)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let contentG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let frameG = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            reviewsStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            reviewsStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            reviewsStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            reviewsStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            reviewsStack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
        ])
        
        let sampleLocs: [String] = [
            "Koblenz, Germany",
            "Westerwald, Germany",
            "Bonn, Germany",
            "Saarbrüken, Germany",
        ]
        let sampleRevs: [String] = [
            "For some reason, I am failing to make the UIView (Gray box from the top light gray line to the bottom one) resize correctly.",
            "A Single Line",
            "The white text inside it (Actual review) is longer than 1 line and should not get cut off, only when reaching a maximum of say 5 lines.",
            "The thing is, it works when I don't set width and height constraints for the user image you see on the left side. Removing those will make the view resize correctly, but it will completely distort the image.",
            "Another Single Line",
            "The image top and botton anchors seem to be glued to the anchors in its horizontal stackview, which again are stuck to the UIView's top and botton anchors with constants, as it should.",
        ]
        let sampleStars: [String] = [
            "5", "4", "3", "2", "1",
        ]
        for i in 0..<sampleRevs.count {
            let v = JanView()
            v.nameLabel.text = "Clara R."
            v.locLabel.text = sampleLocs[i % sampleLocs.count]
            v.reviewTextLabel.text = sampleRevs[i]
            v.publishedLabel.text = "Published less than 24h ago"
            v.starValueLabel.text = sampleStars[i % sampleStars.count]
            if let img = UIImage(named: "prof") {
                v.reviewerImageView.image = img
            }
            reviewsStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
            let sepView = UIView()
            sepView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
            sepView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1.0).isActive = true
            reviewsStack.addArrangedSubview(sepView)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Here is how it ends up looking:

[image]